# Azure Table and log4net

Tags: azure, log4net

I create code to save log to azure tables.
And I override ActivateOptions method to create table if it does exist.

```
public override async void ActivateOptions()
        {
            base.ActivateOptions();

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse
                (CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            _tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            await CraeteTablesIfNotExist();
        }

        private async Task CraeteTablesIfNotExist()
        {
            CloudTable logCloudTable = _tableClient.GetTableReference(TableName);
            await logCloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
```

And code to save message to blob storage:

```
protected override async void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                CloudTable cloudTable = _tableClient.GetTableReference(TableName);
                TableBatchOperation tableBatchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

                tableBatchOperation.InsertOrReplace(new LogEntry($"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
                    $"{DateTime.UtcNow:dd HH:mm:ss.fff}-{Guid.NewGuid()}")
                {
                    LoggerName = loggingEvent.LoggerName,
                    Message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage
                });

                await cloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(tableBatchOperation);
            }
            catch (DataServiceRequestException drex)
            {
                ErrorHandler.Error("Couldwrite log entry", drex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler.Error("Exception log entry", ex);
            }
        }
```

It does not work! I don't know why but if I move code from ActivateOptions to constructor tables created success.
Code below runs my ActivateOptions method and logs a message:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Log4NetHandler : TableStorage
{
    private TableStorage _storage;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _storage = new TableStorage();
        _storage.ActivateOptions();
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(_storage);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckLogger()
    {
        Append(new LoggingEvent(new LoggingEventData
        {
            LoggerName = "Taras",
            Message = "Message"
        }));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why if I run ActivateOptions methods table in Azure is not created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try implementing the ActivateOptions method without the async calls?  I have old code that is almost identical to yours which works fine.

```
public override void ActivateOptions()
{
    base.ActivateOptions();

    _account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
    _client = _account.CreateCloudTableClient();
    _table = _client.GetTableReference(TableName);
    _table.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I would like use async calls. And I think what it is possible, but I don't know how :)